# Combine 2 for loops in python

Tags: python, c, for-loop

In C, I can do

```
for(i=0, j=0; i < k; i++, j++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is there an equivalent of that in Python?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: C is a different language with different syntax, so it has different features. Why do you need two variables that, as defined here, are identical?

Comment: It rather depends on what `do stuff` does. Python may have a completely different syntax to accomplish the same result.

Comment: @tadman That was just an example I randomly wrote. Currently I'm writing some code which has a lot of nested for loops, and I'm still working out if having 1 for loop for multiple variables can reduce the number of nested loops i need.

Comment: Showing an example like that would be *significantly* better than this small snippet of context-free code. This might be an XY Problem, after all.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean exactly what you wrote, then not really, because Python does not have C-style loop.

If you actually mean something like "iterate on two collections at the same time" then yes: you compose the two collections into one iterator using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) or [`zip_longuest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    ...
```

That works with arbitrary collections so e.g.

```py
for i, j in zip(range(k), itertools.count()):
    ...
```

will perform the same traversal of `i` and `j` your C example does, assuming the loop body does not actually update either. Which obviously makes your example not very useful, because `i` and `j` always have the same value.

If `i` and `j` need to be updated during the loop, then your only recourse is to use a fully desugared `while` loop and manual increment, possibly an offset rather than two counters. Because, again, Python doesn't have C-style loops.